# How to create or convert from input to output optimized way?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, recursion

I'm trying to create path in array of object based on parent child relationship using below code and getting maximum call stack size exceeded error

```
var input = [{
        clientArrngmntId: 12,
        level: 1,
        hasChild: true,
        parentId: 0,
        idx: 0,
    },
    {
        clientArrngmntId: 13,
        level: 2,
        hasChild: true,
        parentId: 12,
        idx: 2,
    },
    {
        clientArrngmntId: 14,
        level: 3,
        hasChild: false,
        parentId: 13,
        idx: 3,
    },
    {
        clientArrngmntId: 15,
        level: 2,
        hasChild: false,
        parentId: 12,
        idx: 4,
    },
    {
        clientArrngmntId: 16,
        level: 1,
        hasChild: false,
        parentId: 0,
        idx: 5,
    }]
    
    var output = [{
        clientArrngmntId: 12,
        level: 1,
        hasChild: true,
        parentId: 0,
        path:[12],
        idx: 0,
    },
    {
        clientArrngmntId: 13,
        level: 2,
        hasChild: true,
        parentId: 12,
        path: [12,13],
        idx: 2,
    },
    {
        clientArrngmntId: 14,
        level: 3,
        hasChild: false,
        parentId: 13,
        path: [12,13,14],
        idx: 3,
    },
    {
        clientArrngmntId: 15,
        level: 2,
        hasChild: false,
        parentId: 12,
        path: [12,15],
        idx: 4,
    },
    {
        clientArrngmntId: 16,
        level: 1,
        hasChild: false,
        parentId: 0,
        path: [16]
        idx: 5,
    }]


const processDataAlt = data => {
    const flattenedData = []
    const flattenRowRecursive = (row, parentPath) => {
        const dataPath = [ ...parentPath, row.clientArrngmntId ]
        flattenedData.push({
            ...row,
            dataPath,
        })
        if (row.hasChild && !flattenedData.includes(row.clientArrngmntId)) {
            flattenRowRecursive(row, dataPath)
        }
    }
    data.forEach(row => flattenRowRecursive(row, []))
    return flattenedData
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a path in an array of objects based on the parent-child relationship without causing a call stack size exceeded error, you can use an iterative approach rather than a recursive one.

Here's an example of how you can achieve this using a loop to build the path for each object in the input array:

```js
var input = [{
clientArrngmntId: 12,
level: 1,
hasChild: true,
parentId: 0,
idx: 0,
},
{
clientArrngmntId: 13,
level: 2,
hasChild: true,
parentId: 12,
idx: 2,
},
{
clientArrngmntId: 14,
level: 3,
hasChild: false,
parentId: 13,
idx: 3,
},
{
clientArrngmntId: 15,
level: 2,
hasChild: false,
parentId: 12,
idx: 4,
},
{
clientArrngmntId: 16,
level: 1,
hasChild: false,
parentId: 0,
idx: 5,
}];

// Create a map to store the paths based on clientArrngmntId
const pathMap = [];

// Iterate over each object in the input array
input.forEach(obj => {
const path = [obj.clientArrngmntId]; // Initialize the path with the current clientArrngmntId
let parentId = obj.parentId;

// Traverse the parent hierarchy to build the complete path
while (parentId !== 0) {
    const parentObj = input.find(parent => parent.clientArrngmntId === parentId);
    path.unshift(parentObj.clientArrngmntId);
    parentId = parentObj.parentId;
}

// pathMap[obj.clientArrngmntId] = path; // Store the path in the map
pathMap.push(Object.assign(obj, {path: path}))

});

console.log(pathMap); // Output the paths for each object
```